# Complex translation and rotation

Tags: complex-numbers

I am having trouble finding the formula for a rotation by $\frac{\pi}{3}$ about the point $ 1+i $.

$$ \widetilde{z} = z \space - (1+i) $$
$$ e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}*\widetilde{z} $$

So I am having trouble translating back.

\begin{align*}
T(z) = e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}(z-1-i)+(1+i)
\\
= e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}*z-e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}(1+i)+(1+i)
\\
= (\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}))*z-e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}(1+i)+(1+i)
\end{align*}

How would I foil out $ -e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}(1+i) $?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can either exploit the values $\cos(\pi/3)=1/2$ and $\sin(\pi/3)=\sqrt{3}/2$ or transform $1+i$ to polar form $\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}$

Comment: The notation $\bar z$ is widely used for the complex conjugate of $z$, so it's not a good choice to hijack it for something completely different here.

Comment: I used a tilde not a bar but sorry for the confusion non the less.

Comment: `having trouble translating back` Is the question about "*translating back*" to cartesian form, or finding the inverse transformation $T^{-1}\,$?

Comment: translating back to cartesian form. I am sorry I will be more explicit next time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get your question.

You've started off correctly, by transforming $z$ to $z'$ (I prefer this to avoid confusion with the conjugate) where $z'$ has the same positional relationship with the centre of rotation $(1+i)$ as $z$ has with the origin.

So $z' = z - (1+i)$.

Now rotate by $\frac{\pi}{3}$ counterclockwise to get:

$e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}z' = e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}(z-(1+i))$

Finally reverse the original translation to get:

$e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}(z-(1+i)) + (1+i)$

This is a correct formula for the required transformation. You can simplify it a bit by putting everything in polar notation. $(1+i) = \sqrt 2e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$, so the final expression becomes:

$ze^{i\frac{\pi}{3}} - \sqrt 2(e^{i\frac{7\pi}{12}} - e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})$